# Is there any way to improve my py3 code for a binary search tree question?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I am working on a python3 question about BST from https://www.testdome.com/questions/python/binary-search-tree/24973?visibility=1&skillId=9:

Binary search tree (BST) is a binary tree where the value of each node is larger or equal to the values in all the nodes in that node's left subtree and is smaller than the values in all the nodes in that node's right subtree.

Write a function that, **efficiently with respect to time used**, checks if a given binary search tree contains a given value.

For example, for the following tree:

- n1 (Value: 1, Left: null, Right: null)
- n2 (Value: 2, Left: n1, Right: n3)
- n3 (Value: 3, Left: null, Right: null)

Call to contains(n2, 3) should return True since a tree with root at n2 contains number 3.

My code is:

```
import collections

Node = collections.namedtuple('Node', ['left', 'right', 'value'])

def contains(root, value):
    if value == root.value:
        return True

    if value > root.value:
        if root.right != None:
            return contains(root.right, value)
    else:
        if root.left != None:
            return contains(root.left, value)


n1 = Node(value=1, left=None, right=None)
n3 = Node(value=3, left=None, right=None)
n2 = Node(value=2, left=n1, right=n3)

print(contains(n2, 3))
```

It can work but the website only gave me 33 scores. I found some similar questions, but they are based on c++. I want to know is there any way to improve my code to get a better score based on python3?

Thank you!!

Comment: This would be better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your code never returns `False`, so python automatically returns a `None` instead. Just adding a `return False` at the very last line of `contains` function would suffice.

```
def contains(root, value):
    if value == root.value:
        return True

    if value > root.value:
        if root.right != None:
            return contains(root.right, value)
    else:
        if root.left != None:
            return contains(root.left, value)
    return False
```